# How can I detect that MediaPlayer object starts playing?

Tags: android, media, android-mediaplayer

I'm working with `setNextMediaPlayer()` method to make a gapless playback music player.

`setNextMediaPlayer()` is a great method to enable gapless playback but there was a problem for me to refresh the information of the next coming song to layouts. When I use `setNextMediaPlayer()` method, I don't need to use `start()` method to start playback so there's no way to catch when the playback starts exactly. 
Alternatively, I put my information refreshing method in `onCompletion` but it has a limit.

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion():");
    displayInfoSingle(nextItem);//refresh albumart and song info.
}
```

Is there any listener to detect when `MediaPlayer` object starts playback?

**Added after Tarun Varshney's answer>>>**

I'm using `setNextMediaPlayer()` as below to play `mp2` next to `mp1` seamlessly.

```
mp2 = new MediaPlayer();
mp2.setDataSource(nextItem.getUri());
mp2.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mp2.prepare();
mp1.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);
```

`mp2` already might be prepared before its playback because of `**mp2.prepare();**` so `onPreparedListener` will not be called at the right time I want.
Is there any other way to set `mp2` as a parameter of `setNextMediaPlayer` of `mp1`?

Answer (score 4):

```
public void setOnPreparedListener (MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener listener)
```

This might work for you.

Comment: I ended up using VideoView.setOnPreparedListener. This was enough to cover my problem (play button drawable change to pause)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I already make next MediaPlayer Object prepared in advance, please see my additional question.